# Два почти одинаковых фрагмента

Tags: android, android-fragment

Есть `ViewPager` с страницами. Макет фрагментов-страниц, как показано на рисунках

[image]
[image]

По сути фрагменты отличаются наличием картинки под вопросом в первом случае и  картинками под радиобатонами во втором.

Как правильно реализовать данную разметку и фрагменты?

В голову пришли 2 варианта:

1. Напихать сразу все view в один layout и в одном классе фрагмента
   контролить их видимость в зависимости от типа вопроса.
2. Разбить разметку на 2 разных файла, к каждому типу страницы
   сделать класс фрагмента.

В первом случае на классе фрагменте лежит лишняя функциональность. Во втором случае 2 фрагмента имеют почти одну и туже функциональность. (Отличаются загрузкой картинок в разные места).

Comment: Да как на такие вопросы то отвечать? Здесь можно сделать как вам нравится, как удобней, это очень маленькая задача, в коде можно оформить как хотите. Все что могу посоветовать, сделать это в 1 фрагменте и разделить его на viewState, это быстрей и проще. Завтра у вас будет вопрос, где 4чек бокса с 1 картинкой, вы будете новый фрагмент делать ? Нет. Поэтому делайте в 1м с разными стейт, позже когда , Quiz ваш станет большим и отличий между вопросами будут большие можете подумать об разделении на разные фрагменты, по мне так проще.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei Я бы сделал с разу в разных фрагментах, для разметки можно использовать include, проблемы продублировать код по загрузке картинок я не вижу, а так усложнять фрагмент и при его расширении думать о его возможном разделении. + производительнее будут экраны, в первом случае можно использовать например LinearLayout только, во втором ещё RecycleView

Comment: *во втором случае достаточно даже RecycleView